# Read More excerpt link on a post is not linking to the post itself

Tags: excerpt

My Read More link on several pages (showing an excerpt of those posts) is not linking to the posts themselves when you click on Read More.  It looks like it is a link and should do so, but it just update the same page and keeps you on that same page...

I don't know how to code so very very basic layman's terms is greatly appreciated. I am using Astra Theme if that makes a difference at all.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Can you please provide the URL where this is happening?

Comment: https://hollyshighlights.com/book-and-resource-review/personal/

Comment: I see the problem. But it's hard to predict the issue without checking the backend. Let me know if I can access the backend anyhow. Thanks

Comment: Is there a day and time that might work for you and I could screen share through Zoom?  I greatly appreciate your assistance with resolving this. It's on multiple pages with any post I put on (using the excerpt option in the menu tab). Thank you.

Comment: Yes, we can work it out today. Do let me know what time is suitable for you.

Comment: Oh thank you SO much! I just got home and can do anytime (it's currently 7pm here). I have zoom and can email you a link to join me if you wouldn't mind posting your email address? Thank you for your willingness to help me.

Comment: If you want to just let me know a day and time that works for you, as well as an email to send the zoom link then I'll make sure we connect. Thank you again for your willingness to help me. I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: You can contact me at sahil@jdperoro.com

Comment: Please do not share backend access.